# Schrodinger's derivation of point particle motion from waves

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, waves

On p. 30 of Schrodinger's Collected Papers on Wave Mechanics (1928, 2nd ed) he is deriving the equations of motion for a point particle under the assumption that Hamilton's principle function $W$ represents the phase of a wave ($\times\hbar$) and that a "material point" is just the point in space where "all phases exactly agree" for a wave pulse, so that they all constructively interfere.

He starts off by considering a wave with the average frequency and wavenumber of the wave pulse and denotes its phase $W(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4, x,y,z,t)$. The $\alpha_i$'s are the constants of integration associated with solving the HJE, and he uses them to parameterize the frequency and wavenumber at a chosen point $(\mathbf r_0, t_0) = (x_0,y_0,z_0,t_0)$. He then constructs an infinitesimally similar wave (similar frequency and wavenumber) by giving it a phase with infinitesimally varied $\alpha_i$'s. To first order expansion this results in
$$W' = W + \frac{\partial W}{\partial \alpha_1}\mathrm d\alpha_1 + \frac{\partial W}{\partial \alpha_2}\mathrm d\alpha_2 + \frac{\partial W}{\partial \alpha_3}\mathrm d\alpha_3 + \frac{\partial W}{\partial \alpha_4}\mathrm d\alpha_4$$
Then the wave pulse is formed by the superposition of the set of waves consisting of all combinations of the infinitesimal $\mathrm d\alpha_i$'s.

**Questions:**

My first question has to do with his assumption that the phases of this set of waves "*exactly agree*" at the chosen point. To me this means that the phases are *equal* at that point, but this means for any 2 phases from the set :
\begin{align*}
&W_0 + \sum_{i=1}^4\frac{\partial W}{\partial \alpha_i}\bigg|_0\mathrm d\alpha_i = W_0 + \sum_{i=1}^4\frac{\partial W}{\partial \alpha_i}\bigg|_0\mathrm d\alpha'_i \\
\implies &\sum_{i=1}^4\frac{\partial W}{\partial \alpha_i}\bigg|_0(\mathrm d\alpha_i - \mathrm d\alpha'_i) = 0
\end{align*}
Since each $\mathrm d\alpha_i$ is arbitrary and can be chosen independently the coefficients have to be independently $0$ to satisfy this, meaning the partial derivatives are $0$ at $(\mathbf r_0, t_0)$. But this is contrary to what the HJE says which is that these partial derivatives are non-zero constants along the classical trajectory, which is what he ends up deriving. So how can we assume the phases agree exactly if it leads to this contradiction?

My second question has to do with how he goes on to derive that the partial derivatives are constant along the curve of agreeing phase. He says that for the phases to all be equal at a point the $\frac{\partial W}{\partial a_i}$'s at that point must be equal in value to what they were at the initial point of agreeing phase $(\mathbf r_0, t_0)$, so that along the trajectory $\mathbf r(t) = (x(t),y(t),z(t))$:
$$\frac{\partial W}{\partial \alpha_i}\bigg|_{(r(t),t)} = \frac{\partial W}{\partial \alpha_i}\bigg|_{(\mathbf r_0,t_0)}$$

He doesn't really show how he got to this, and I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.